# How to modify an input in bash script?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I want to do the following on a bash script:

I want the user to enter a file name and the bash script must move the file to another file as follows. If the user enters `input.tex`, I want to move this file to another file named `inputmerged.tex`.

I have the following bash script named `myscript.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
mv $1 $2
```

The above however needs to be run as `./myscript input.tex inputmerged.tex`
The second input is redundant, since the new file, which I move to, is of the same type and always has the word `merged` appended at the end of the first filename. How should I do it to get rid of the second input in the bash script?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
NEWFILE=`echo ${1} | sed "s/\./merged./"`
mv "${1}" "${NEWFILE}"
```

This will however fail if there are multiple `.` characters in the name.

Comment: Or just `mv "$1" "${1%.tex}merged.tex"`.  http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/030